# Looping through array of objects and reducing on multiple key/pairs

Tags: javascript

I have a large array of objects and I am trying to consolidate to where I have one array of objects that looks like below:
Each item(ex:banana) will be in 2 separate objects as I am trying to aggregate all buy orders and sell orders, and these are different prices/data.

I have tried grabbing the unique pairings (banana, apple, orange, etc.) and mapping through that and inside another map of the data, but I can't figure it out.

```
let uniquePairing = Array.from([...new Set(data.map(item => item["name"]))])


**let data = [{
name:'banana,
price:( average cost)
type:buy
items: ( total bananas)
fee: ( total fees)
},
{
name:'banana,
price:( average cost)
type:sell
items: ( total bananas)
fee: ( total fees)
},
{ apples...
]**
```

Example of data

```
let data = [
{
name:"banana",
price:1,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"banana",
price:1.2,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"banana",
price:2,
type: "sell",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"apple",
price:1,
type: "buy"
fee: 0.5
items:25
},
{
name:"apple",
price:1.2,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"apple",
price:2,
type: "sell",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
}
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to aggregate by `type`?

Comment: Is the line `let uniquePairing =  ...` your entire solution attempt? What did that return? Doesn't look like you've put much thought into this yet.

Comment: Yes by type and item name

Comment: Of course not,  that only gets the the unique pairings possible, I have been at this for 2 hours trying different approaches, it would not be beneficial as it would be a total mess to put what I have done here as I am lost in my own code just trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
   let data = [
{
name:"banana",
price:1,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"banana",
price:1.2,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"banana",
price:2,
type: "sell",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"apple",
price:1,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"apple",
price:1.2,
type: "buy",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
},
{
name:"apple",
price:2,
type: "sell",
fee: 0.5,
items:25
}
]

const getFruitData = (fruits, fruit) => fruits.filter(fr=> fr.name===fruit.name && fr.type=== fruit.type)

const getTotal = (fruits, field) => fruits.reduce((acc,cur)=> acc+=cur[field], 0)

const isRegistered = (fruits, value) => fruits.some(fruit=> fruit.type === value.type && fruit.name===value.name)

const getFruits = (fruits) => {
  return fruits.reduce((acc, cur)=> {
if(isRegistered(acc, cur)){
  return acc
}
acc.push({name: cur.name, type: cur.type})
return acc
  }, [])
}

function mergeData(arr){
  const fruits = getFruits(arr)
  return fruits.map(fruit=> {
const data = getFruitData(arr, fruit)
return {
  name: fruit.name,
  price: getTotal(data, "price"),
  type: fruit.type,
  fee: getTotal(data, "fee"),
  items: getTotal(data, "items")
}
  })
}

console.log(mergeData(data))
```

Comment: Each item ( banana) would have 2 objects. One with the aggregated banana buy order data and another for the aggregated sell order data

Comment: Ok, I misread your original request. I've modified the function. The output is fine now. If it works for you, you can mark this answer as valid (and maybe remove your downvote too).

Comment: Thanks, that works !.. Im going to take some time to digest and learn from your code as I have not coded in a long while. Im getting stuck on the most trivial of things atm.

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions about the code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the `reduce` function:

```
let uniquePairing = data.reduce((total, currentObj) => {
  const name = currentObj.name,
  type = currentObj.type;

  // Group by both `type` and `name`
  let relatedObj = total.find(obj => obj.name === name && obj.type === type);
  if (!relatedObj) {
    total.push({
    ...currentObj,

    // Adding `totalPrice` and `objCount` to track the cost average
    totalPrice: currentObj.price,
    objCount: 1
  })
} else {
  relatedObj.totalPrice += currentObj.price;
  relatedObj.objCount++;
  relatedObj.price = relatedObj.totalPrice / relatedObj.objCount;
  relatedObj.items += currentObj.items;
  relatedObj.fee += currentObj.fee;
}

  return total;
}, []);
```

Comment: This works as well, thanks.